# macOS Catalina Mail creates Recovered Messages repeatedly

Tags: mail.app, catalina

After upgrading to Catalina Apple Mail started to behave differently. In particular, sending email became very slow/delayed and this, I believe, (re)creates Recovered Messages On My Mac mailbox. First, you can notice Outbox lasting long and the Recovered Messages appears in On My Mac mailbox even if you delete all of those previously. So, each sending is long and makes this happen.

I have a similar problem. I updated to Catalina 10.15.2 today, and the problem is still showing. Each time I write a new message, Mail creates a bunch of new "Recovered Messages" local mailbox with copies of the message.
I tried to Rebuild the Mailbox as Apple recommends in that case, but the problem didn't go away.